# table of contents: adding a vertical space

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

In a table of contents that has been generated with LaTeX's `\tableofcontents` command, I would like to add a vertical space before a Chapter item in the table of contents. One way that I have in my notes is to use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{10pt}}
```

at a desired location in the document so that this gets processed by `\tableofcontents` to include an appropriate vertical space in the table of contents. I have two questions:

1. Is the above the correct way to get a vertical space in a table of contents?
2. Why is it necessary to use the `\protect` command here?

Thank you...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. It's the correct way if it's just for fine tuning the final appearance of the table of contents; if it's a general need for all chapters, customizing directly the table of contents typesetting would be preferable.
2. `\addtocontents` writes to the `.toc` file and this causes commands to be *expanded*, but you want to write `\vspace{10pt}` in the `.toc` file, not the instructions to leave a space (that will be done when the `.toc` file is read).