# Modify ToC Backmatter Entry Distance

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, memoir

I created a simple document using `memoir` class as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{memoir}

\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
% modify ToC part
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{16pt}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{2.5em}
% modify ToC chapter
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalsize}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{2pt}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2.5em}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{Part One}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}

\part{Part Two}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}

\backmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter[About Writer]{About Writer}

\end{document}
```

[image: My result]

How can I add more space (say 16pt) between `About Writer` and the last chapter in ToC (like those between `Part One` and `Part Two`)? Thanks.

UPDATE: Both [Karlkoeller's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228657/modify-toc-backmatter-entry-distance/228658#228658) and [Johannes_B's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228657/modify-toc-backmatter-entry-distance/228662#228662) answers worked fine if I used `\chapter[About Writer]{About Writer}`. But when I used `\include{aboutwriter}` (as @barbara-beeton [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228657/modify-toc-backmatter-entry-distance?noredirect=1#comment539425_228657)), they didn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{memoir}

\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
% modify ToC part
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{16pt}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{2.5em}
% modify ToC chapter
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalsize}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{2pt}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2.5em}

% Karlkoeller said:
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto{\backmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{16pt}}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{Part One}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}

\part{Part Two}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}

\backmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
% \chapter[About Writer]{About Writer}

% Johannes_B said:
% \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{16pt}}

\include{aboutwriter} % Include external file

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, have a look at [table of contents: adding a vertical space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23036)

Comment: @Johannes_B: I added `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{16pt}}`. It didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Sure it does, @karlkoeller is doing exactly the same below.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I've double checked but adding `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{16pt}}` (or even greater number) seems doesn't work for me. I'm pretty new to LaTeX. I might have made mistakes. Thanks.

Comment: the suggested `\addtocontents` *should work* in the example as shown in the question.  but if in the real situation you are using `\include{aboutwriter}`, the `\addtocontents` will be delayed until after the included file has been processed.  not very useful, but a (poorly) documented side effect of `\include`.  the `\appto{backmatter}` method provided by @karlkoeller gets around that "gotcha".

Comment: @Johannes_B: It works now. Thanks, mate. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks :) It was my fault. I misunderstood. I inserted `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{16pt}}` in the wrong place (in preamble) instead of the body (as Johannes_B has shown below). Now it really works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You're right. When I used `\include{aboutwriter}`, both `\addtocontents` and `\appto{\backmatter}` didn't work. I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: @guest_5758 I've edited my answer. Now it works even with `\include`d files.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thanks, mate :) So you changed `\appto{\backmatter}` to `\preto{\backmatter}`, right?

Comment: @guest_5758 Right. In this way `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{16pt}}` is issued before `\backmatter` and the problem described by Barbara is circumvented.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load the package `etoolbox` and issue

```
\preto{\backmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{16pt}}}
```

In this way, when you issue `\backmatter` a `16pt` skip is added in the ToC.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{memoir}

\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
% modify ToC part
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{16pt}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{2.5em}
% modify ToC chapter
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalsize}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{2pt}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2.5em}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\backmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{16pt}}}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{Part One}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}

\part{Part Two}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}

\backmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter[About Writer]{About Writer}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @guest_5758 you're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The space in the earlier parts comes from `\part` and it is easier, and I think leads to a more simply understood table of contents to use the same mechanism here rather than simply rely on space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a5paper]{memoir}

\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
% modify ToC part
\renewcommand{\cftpartaftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftpartfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftpartpagefont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{16pt}
\setlength{\cftpartnumwidth}{2.5em}
% modify ToC chapter
\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterfont}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalsize}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{2pt}
\setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{2.5em}


\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\part{Part One}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}

\part{Part Two}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}
%\chapter[Chapter Title]{Chapter Title}

\backmatter
\part{The Appendix Bits}
\pagestyle{plain}
\chapter[About Writer]{About Writer}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks :) The problem is now fixed by adding `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and `\preto{\backmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{16pt}}}{}{}` as [mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228657/modify-toc-backmatter-entry-distance/228658#228658) above. Thanks a lot.