# Table of contents: Change vertical spacing for single section

Tags: table-of-contents

My table of contents has the following structure:

```
List of figures.........3
List of acronyms........4
Introduction............6
1 First Section.........7
2 Second Section........8
```

But I want it to have some vertical space between the "introduction" sections and the actual content, like this:

```
List of figures.........3
List of acronyms........4
Introduction............6

1 First Section.........7
2 Second Section........8
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that? I just found some snippets to change the space between the lines in general or for all sections, but nothing about how to change the vertical space just for a single line.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: the answer is explained here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23036/table-of-contents-adding-a-vertical-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add whatever you want to your TOC with the command `\addcontentsline`. I just added 20 pt for you. Just change this to some value which pleases you!

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{3}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\clearpage
\section*{List of acronyms}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of acronyms}
\clearpage\stepcounter{page}{1}
\section*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Introduction}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{20pt}}%
\clearpage
\section{First Section}
\clearpage
\section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I have not added the dots for every line. But I do not know, which document class you use.